# Bootstrap login and signup forms are not aligning

Tags: html, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I want my Signup and Login form at the same place .By default i want to show the Signup form . On Login Button Click event i want Signup form should be replaced by Login form at the same place or position but its not happening . What is happening is Signup form is coming at top while login form is coming at down . To see the result as of now i have removed Visibility css ..
Here is my Markup ..

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="top-content">

  <div class="inner-bg">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-7 text">
          <h1><strong>Custom</strong> Authentication Form</h1>
          <div class="description">
            <p>
              Please register or enter credentials to enjoy the app
            </p>
          </div>

          <!-- Trying to add Angular JS Snippet !-->

          <div ng-controller="LoginController" class="top-big-link">

            <a class="btn btn-link-1" href="" ng-click="$event.preventDefault();Register()">Login</a>
          </div>

        </div>

        <!-- Signup Form Here !-->
        <div ng-controller="SignupformController" class="col-sm-5 form-box">
          <div class="form-top">
            <div class="form-top-left">
              <h3>Sign up now</h3>
              <p>Fill in the form below to get instant access:</p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-top-right">
              <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="form-top-divider"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-bottom">
            <form role="form" action="" method="post" class="registration-form">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="form-first-name">First name</label>
                <input type="text" name="form-first-name" placeholder="First name..." class="form-first-name form-control" id="form-first-name">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="form-last-name">Last name</label>
                <input type="text" name="form-last-name" placeholder="Last name..." class="form-last-name form-control" id="form-last-name">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="form-email">Email</label>
                <input type="text" name="form-email" placeholder="Email..." class="form-email form-control" id="form-email">
              </div>

              <button type="submit" class="btn">Sign me up!</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>

        <!-- Login Form Here !-->

        <div ng-controller="LoginformController" class="col-sm-5 form-box">
          <div class="form-top">
            <div class="form-top-left">
              <h3>Login now</h3>
              <p>Fill in the form below to get instant access:</p>
            </div>
            <div class="form-top-right">
              <i class="fa fa-pencil"></i>
            </div>
            <div class="form-top-divider"></div>
          </div>
          <div class="form-bottom">
            <form role="form" action="" method="post" class="registration-form">
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="UserID">User ID</label>
                <input type="text" name="UserID" placeholder="User ID..." class="form-first-name form-control" id="UserID">
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only" for="Password">Password</label>
                <input type="text" name="Password" placeholder="Password..." class="form-last-name form-control" id="Password">
              </div>

              <button type="submit" class="btn">Login!</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>





      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Please help me to resolve this ..

Comment: How are you managing visibility of div on button click? visibility:hidden or display:none? try with display:none

Comment: where is your javascript?

Comment: use `ng-if` condition for showing and hiding the form

Comment: @Arvaan Display:none worked..Let me try other things also.

Comment: @Arvaan Can i hide or show the angularJS controller ?

Comment: What do mean by show/hide controller? you can hide HTML tags only

Comment: @Arvaan I am able to do my requirement ..Thanks for your support..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I did it:

```
<div class="col-sm-7 text">
     <h1><strong>Atlas</strong> Authentication Form</h1>

    <div class="description">
        <p>Please register or enter credentials to enjoy the app</p>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav nav-pills" id="myTab">
        <li class="active"><a href="#signup" data-toggle="pill">Sign Up</a>        </li>
        <li><a href="#login" data-toggle="pill">Log In</a>        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
</div>
<div class="tab-content">
    <div class="tab-pane active" id="signup">
        <div ng-controller="SignupformController" class="col-sm-5 form-box">
            ...
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="login">
        <div ng-controller="LoginformController" class="col-sm-5 form-box">...</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[Here is the **JSFiddle** demo](https://jsfiddle.net/qxaa50b9/)

What you are actually to achieve is basically the way bootstrap `nav-pills` work. You just need to display the buttons as nav-pills and then set the respective contents in `tab-content` class.

Using `data-toggle="pill"` will automatically switch between the tabs and contents.

(You can add the `fade` class along the `tab-pane` class to give the switching a little effect [like this](https://jsfiddle.net/qxaa50b9/1/) :) )